# Why is my right at position absolute not working?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I'm trying to position my arrow on the right side of the parent div with position relative, but so far I have not managed to do it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="button--collapse">
   <h2 class="title" >Your selection</h2>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.button--collapse {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.button--collapse:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "›";
      color: white;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Add position absolute for right arrow

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question, I already had position: absolute in the arrow.

Comment: Remove `transform` property. Working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3f4u9cro/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a positive length to your right property and then give the parent a bit of padding as the `position:absolute` takes the element out of the documents normal flow.

```css
.button--collapse {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 2rem; /* padding right added to accommodate the after absolute element that si taken out of the normal flow */
}

.button--collapse:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "›";
      color: black;
      right: 10px; /* add 10px to move over from right 10px */
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button--collapse">
   <h2 class="title" >Your selection</h2>
</div>
```